# Adding options to existing optgroup

Tags: jquery

I have a select menu with 3 opt groups. The last one is called "Custom Search" and when you pick it, it will fire a modal to chose a username that isn't in the dropdown and have it added to the database.

Long story short, I want to add a `<option></option>` to the `optgroup` but not too sure how to do that.

Select name is called "selectAgent":

Trying to add an option dynamically to this group.

```html
<optgroup label="Other" id="custom">
    <option value="mentorCustom">Search For Agent</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an adhoc element, set its value and text, and append it to your optgroup:

```js
$("<option>").val("Foo").text("Bar").appendTo("#custom");
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/493qa/